# Android - startActivity(intent) crashes application

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I'm trying to make it so that when a button is pressed this method launches a new activity, but the app crashes before the second activity is ever started. The button corresponds to the method correctly and the new activity is listed in the manifest file.

MainActivity method:

```
public void okay(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, DisplayActivity.class);

        boolean dayofweek, season, daystill;
        dayofweek = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDayofweek)).isChecked();
        season = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxSeason)).isChecked();
        daystill = ((CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBoxDaystill)).isChecked();

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DAYOFWEEK, dayofweek);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SEASON, season);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DAYSTILL, daystill);

        DatePicker datepicker = (DatePicker) findViewById(R.id.datePicker);
        int day, month, year;
        day = datepicker.getDayOfMonth();
        month = datepicker.getMonth();
        year = datepicker.getYear();

        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_DAY, day);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_MONTH, month);
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_YEAR, year);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
```

DisplayActivity:

```
public class DisplayActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        boolean dayofweek = intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_DAYOFWEEK, false);
        boolean season = intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_SEASON, false);
        boolean daystill = intent.getBooleanExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_DAYSTILL, false);
        int day = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_DAY, 0);
        int month = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_MONTH, 0);
        int year = intent.getIntExtra(MainActivity.EXTRA_YEAR, 0);

        TextView output = new TextView(this);
        output.setTextSize(30);

        String s = day + "/" + month + "/" + year + "\n";
        if(dayofweek) s += "";

        output.setText(s);
        setContentView(output);

    }
}
```

Comment: My LogCat gives me absolutely nothing. No messages at all.

Comment: Could you put the error?

Comment: App crashes on findViewById or startActivity line?

Comment: Do you have DisplayActivity declared in your manifest?

Comment: Logcat will display something  you're not looking hard enough or you have filters set

Comment: @Tanis.7x From the OP - `the new activity is listed in the manifest file`

Comment: The only thing logcat is showing is the messages about installing the app onto the device. After that it gives nothing. No exceptions or anything. No filters and it's set to 'verbose'.

Comment: The Dalvik VM logs a crash.  It's worked millions of times for thousands of people.  I sincerely doubt that you are the first person to find a bug in this area.  Please check again carefully.  The only crash I know of that doesn't look like a normal crash is some kind of panic like OOM but even that's there.

Comment: Check that your device is correctly connected to your PC; try also to clean your project (**ant nodeps clean;** in a console for instance) then retry.

Comment: From The code you have shared, there can be multiple causes e.g. null pointers etc. Uninstall and install the app again, try to capture the logcat for the connected Device/emulator. I dont think any one can help you without the logcat.

Comment: Please, put a try{} catch(Exception e){} enclosing all your code, make a debug and tell us about a possible throwed exception